# How can I load an element from the swift bundle that is in a folder?

Tags: swift

I am trying to load the file `a` in the default-sound`. Here is what it look like in the bundle. [image]

I tried to load with a `/` to locate the folder like you would with a normal directory structure.

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

struct TtsPronounciationError: Error {
    enum ErrorKind {
        case loadingError
    }
    
    let kind: ErrorKind
    let path: String;
    let char: Character
    
    init(kind: ErrorKind, path: String, char: Character) {
        self.path = path;
        self.kind = kind
        self.char = char
    }
}

struct TtsPronounciation {
    var char: Character;
    var audioFile: AVAudioPlayer
    
    static func fromBundle(char: Character, bundleFileName: String) throws -> TtsPronounciation {
        Bundle.main.load()
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: bundleFileName, ofType: nil) {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
                let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                return self.init(char: char, audioFile: sound)
            } catch let e {
                print(#function, "error", e)
                throw TtsPronounciationError(kind: .loadingError, path: bundleFileName, char: char)
            }
        } else {
            print(#function, " - error", "could not find \(bundleFileName)")
            throw TtsPronounciationError(kind: .loadingError, path: bundleFileName, char: char)
        }
    }
}

do {
    var a = try TtsPronounciation.fromBundle(char: "a", bundleFileName: "default-sound/a")
}
catch {
    print("could not find the file in bundle")
}
```

Secondly I tried to use the inDirectory parameter of the function `Bundle.main.path` as I think it's used to locate file that are stored in a directory of the bundle.

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

struct TtsPronounciationError: Error {
    enum ErrorKind {
        case loadingError
    }
    
    let kind: ErrorKind
    let path: String;
    let char: Character
    
    init(kind: ErrorKind, path: String, char: Character) {
        self.path = path;
        self.kind = kind
        self.char = char
    }
}

struct TtsPronounciation {
    var char: Character;
    var audioFile: AVAudioPlayer
    
    static func fromBundle(char: Character, bundleFileName: String, inDirectory: String?) throws -> TtsPronounciation {
        Bundle.main.load()
        
        if let path = inDirectory != nil ? Bundle.main.path(forResource: bundleFileName, ofType: nil, inDirectory: inDirectory) : Bundle.main.path(forResource: bundleFileName, ofType: nil) {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
                let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                return self.init(char: char, audioFile: sound)
            } catch let e {
                print(#function, "error", e)
                throw TtsPronounciationError(kind: .loadingError, path: bundleFileName, char: char)
            }
        } else {
            print(#function, " - error", "could not find \(bundleFileName)")
            throw TtsPronounciationError(kind: .loadingError, path: bundleFileName, char: char)
        }
    }
}

do {
   var a = try TtsPronounciation.fromBundle(char: "a", bundleFileName: "a", inDirectory: "default-sound")
}
catch {
    print("could not locate the sound")
}
```

Comment: The items in the Asset Catalog are no accessible with `path(forResource`. Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1913/_index.html By the way there is also `url(forResource:withExtension:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't that it's in a folder. It's in an asset catalog. You access data assets (such as audio) with NSDataAsset. This specific example is covered by [QA1913 Accessing Audio Files in Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1913/_index.html):

```
if let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"Sound"){

   do {
         // Use NSDataAsset's data property to access the audio file stored in Sound.
          player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:asset.data, fileTypeHint:"caf")
         // Play the above sound file.
         player?.play()
   } catch let error as NSError {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

In your case, you'd replace "Sound" with "a".

Comment: is there a way I still can use the directory structure?

Comment: You would need to move this out of the asset catalog to do that. Asset catalogs are optimized in ways that don't allow direct URL access. To maintain the directory structure, make sure to create the folder in Xcode as a Folder Reference, not a Group (otherwise the folder structure will be flattened).

Comment: (Note that you can call this `"default-sound/a"` rather than `"a"` if you want, if that's what you mean. For full details see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html) This would then be `NSDataAsset(name: "default-sound/a")`

Comment: What is the difference between the asset catalog and the bundle?

Comment: An Asset Catalog is contained in the bundle. It's an optimized way of storing various kinds of assets. They're often pre-processed in order to be most efficient on the target device, and supports things like automatically managing resolutions.